# How can I run a query to systematically add up the results to a table or list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Basically, this is what I want to do.

If the data set is this:

```
|----------------------------------------------|
|ShopName      |Fruit                          |
|----------------------------------------------|
|Kens Shop     |Eggplant                       |
|Kens Shop     |Potato                         |
|Kens Shop     |Asparagus                      |
|Bens Shop     |Eggplant                       |
|Bens Shop     |Carrot                         |
|Sarahs Shop   |Potato                         |
|Sarahs Shop   |Asparagus                      |
------------------------------------------------
```

The result that I want is:

```
----------------------------------
|Vegetable   |Count              |
|---------------------------------
|Eggplant    |2                  |
|Potato      |2                  |
|Asparagus   |2                  |
|Carrot      |1                  |
----------------------------------
```

For this particular example, I don't really care about how many the store has of the vegetables.

And, ideally, I'd like to put the "Shop names" in to a multi line text box and iterate through it through a C# ASP.NET frontend, and then bind it all back to a GridView for viewing.

```
 For Each strLine As String In TextBox1.Text.Split(vbNewLine)
            ' somehow add the results of this "shop" to an existing table or list, and add the results to what is already there
        Next
```

If I could somehow do this using Linq to SQL, that would be additionally brilliant.

So.... what would be the Linq to SQL logic to make something like this happen? Or if its not possible, can it be done in basic SQL queries?

Thanks :)

Comment: Could you post the SQL you have tried already?

Comment: Well, lousily on my part I guess, I don't even know where to *start*.  I know I can write something that is detailed at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp to start with, but I don't know how I would get each subsequent query to add to the already existing table (or list).

Comment: Try select fruit, count(*) from tableName
group by fruit to get you started! Move on from there and you can post a comment or chat me with questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Syntax

```
SELECT Fruit AS Vegetable, Count(*) AS [Count] 
    FROM Shops 
    GROUP BY Fruit
```

Linq Syntax ( Pseudo code - can be optimized ). First create two helper `struct` that handles the input and grouped output.

```
struct Shop
{
    public string ShopName { get; set; }
    public string Fruit { get; set; }
}
struct GrouppedFruit
{
    public string Vegetable { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Now query the DataBase to return the `SELECT` query and insert it into a List

```
DataTable table = manager.GetData("SELECT * FROM Shops");
var shops = new List<Shop>();
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    shops.Add(new Shop
    {
        ShopName = row["ShopName"].ToString(),
        Fruit = row["Fruit"].ToString()
    });
}
```

Grouped output using LINQ

```
//query syntax
var grouppedFruits = (from shop in shops
                        group shop by shop.Fruit into grouping
                        select new GrouppedFruit
                        {
                            Vegetable = grouping.Key,
                            Count = grouping.Count()
                        }).ToList();
//method syntax
var grouppedFruits1 = shops
    .GroupBy(shop => shop.Fruit)
    .Select(g => new GrouppedFruit 
    { 
        Vegetable = g.Key, 
        Count = g.Count() 
    }).ToList();
```